# Android koush ion library catch 401 error

Tags: android, http-status-code-401, android-ion

I'm using [Koush Ion](https://github.com/koush/ion) on Android to handle net operations.
I'd like to add a common handler to handle 401 unauthorized error.
How i can do it?

thank you

Answer (score 3):

```
Ion.with(this)
            .load("http://google.com")
            .asString()
            .withResponse()
            .setCallback(new FutureCallback<Response<String>>() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted(Exception e, Response<String> result) {
                    if(result.getHeaders().code()){
                        // ............
                    }
                }
            });
```

goodluck!

Comment: Oh no, you can use "onHeader" and it works very well